# How to transfer cookies using a query "$.ajax({"

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies

Simple question:
Using a query like:

```
$.getJSON("http://server.com/con/?callback=?",
        function(data){
```

the server cookie may be visible,

using a query such as:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://server.com/con/,
```

the server can not see the cookie.

How to transfer cookies using a query "**$.ajax({**"?

Answer (score 0):

In Ajax too you can pass cookies like :

> `var cookie_value = "your cookie value";`

```
$.ajax({
  url : "http://server.com/con/",
  type: "post",
  dataType : "json",
  data : {
    'your_cookie_label' : cookie_value
  }, 
  success(function(success_rec) {
    console.log(success_rec,":success_rec");
  }

});
```